# How to groupby week from a given date range SQL Server and return count 0 if no data found for a week

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want the selected data in below format.

```
TOTAL_FEE                WEEK
+---------------+--------------+
  24000                 WEEK_1
  24000                 WEEK_2
  24000                 WEEK_3
```

My query that give me result groupby date is :

```
select  count(*) * 24000, CAST(p.submited_date  AS DATE)
from Form_For_Business_Name_Registration p 
where p.STATUS !='NS' 
and CAST(p.submited_date  AS DATE)>='2016-01-22' 
and CAST(p.submited_date  AS DATE)<='2016-03-04'   
GROUP BY CAST(p.submited_date  AS DATE)
```

What i want is to get results groupby weeks but weeks should be calculated from the given date range.

Note : if there is no data for the week it should return 0 counts for that week.

Will somebody guide me to write a SQL query to get desired output.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP BY WEEK with SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278552/group-by-week-with-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), like:

```
DATEPART(week, submited_date)
```

I would advise using the week number and year number (similar to MySQL's WeekYear) in order to ensure the grouping is specific to that year's week.

Comment: Thank you Anthony.. it is what i was looking for .

Comment: I more help... What is happening now is , it returns me 2 rows if data is found for 2 weeks . What i want is , if there is no data for the week it should return 0 counts for that week.

Comment: This is a common goal that (generally) requires having a utility table that has every date ( a calendar table, as suggested in another answer ) that you can use to join your current table, allowing for those "empty dates" to be used for a 0 count row. I asked the exact same question (only for mysql) probably 5 or 7 years ago.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071595/generate-a-row-in-an-aggregation-query-for-a-date-with-no-results-against-it ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120196/how-can-i-create-a-series-of-months-to-join-sparse-data-to ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310839/sql-group-by-including-empty-rows ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575271/generate-empty-rows-even-if-empty-between-2-dates ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122510/mysql-query-to-get-non-data-for-unassigned-dates

Answer (score 0):

You can take the difference to calculate weeks:

```
select count(*) * 24000,
       (DATEDIFF(day, CAST(p.submited_date AS DATE), '2016-01-22') / 7) as weeknum
from Form_For_Business_Name_Registration p 
where p.STATUS <> 'NS' and
      CAST(p.submited_date  AS DATE) >= '2016-01-22' and
      CAST(p.submited_date  AS DATE) <= '2016-03-04'   
group by (DATEDIFF(day, CAST(p.submited_date AS DATE), '2016-01-22') / 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if I understood what you want)

> GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, p.submited_date)

Answer (score 0):

I recommed using calendar table...Below is the sample query output from calendar table..once you have the table,all you need to do is join two tables and filter rows...

[image]

**EX:**

```
create table 
#test
(
tt datetime
)

insert into #test
select dateadd(day,-n,getdate())
from numbers 
where n<10


select 
* from 
#test

---now if i want to find which week those fall,all i have to do is join calendar table

select 
tt,wkno
from 
#test t1
join 
calendar c
on c.date=t1.tt
```